# Submenu in dropdown works fine on desktop view but no submenu in mobile/tab view?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

The submenu in dropdown works fine on desktop view but no submenu in mobile/tab view?
there is the code

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children right">
   <a href="#">Classes
       <div class="canvas_wrapper">
         <canvas class="menu_dashed">
         </canvas>
       </div>
   </a>
   <span class='button_open'>
   </span>

   <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item back"><a href="#"><em>←</em>&nbsp;BACK</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="dance.html">Dance</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="language.html">Languages</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="others.html">Others</a></li>
      </ul> 
</li>
```

Comment: if you don't share the code then how can  we  help you

Comment: Ive added my menu

Comment: Use media queries in CSS (for example) to make it more responsive. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Check with a google tools for mobile device compactibility. 
Once done, you'll have all dependencies unsupported specified.